# How many stones are white?

Tags: probability

Assuming there's a pipe infinitely generating black or white stones randomly, with each color having 50% chance.

Now someone randomly get 105 stones from the pipe, then randomly put 100 in bowl A and 5 stones in bowl B. It happened that all 5 stones in bowl B are white.

Question: in the 100 stones in bowl A, how many are white?

There are several ideas here

**Idea A**: Since the pipe generates black or white stones as the same 50% chance, the stones in bowl A shall also have 50%-50% distribution. So the expected value of white stones in the  100 stones in blow A, is $$50\% * 100 =50$$.

**Idea B**: Though the pipe generates black or white stones as the same 50%-50% chance, the 105 stones collected could have different distribution due to the randomness of generation. However, since bowl A (100 stones) and B (5 stones) are taken from the same "batch", we assume they have the same distribution, so:

$$E(W_A \mid W_B=5) = \sum_{x=1}^{100} \left[ x P(W_A=x \mid W_B=5) \right] =\sum_{x=1}^{100} \left[x \frac{P(W_A=x\, \mathop{\mathtt{AND}}\, W_B=5) } { P(W_B=5)} \right] = \sum_{x=1}^{100} \left[x \frac{P(W_A=x) P(W_B=5 \mid W_A=x) } { P(W_B=5)}\right]$$, where $$P(W_B=5) = \sum_{x=1}^{100} [ P(W_A=x) P(W_B=5 \mid W_A=x)]$$. Then $P(W_A=x)$, $P(W_B=5 | W_A=x)$ both follows binomial distribution.

**Idea C**: Though the pipe generates black or white stones as the same 50%-50% chance, the 105 stones collected could have different distribution due to the randomness of generation. However, since bowl A (100 stones) and B (5 stones) are taken from the same "batch", we assume they have the same distribution. But we shall not calculate the $x$ as Ideal B, instead, we shall find the $\hat x$ so that 
$$P_{\hat x}(W_B=5) = \max_x P(W_B=5)$$.
This leads to $\hat x= 100$, so the estimation is $W_A =100$.

**Idea D**: Though the pipe generates black or white stones as the same 50%-50% chance, the 105 stones collected could have different distribution due to the randomness of generation. However, since bowl A (100 stones) and B (5 stones) are taken from the same "batch", we assume they have the same distribution. But we shall not calculate the $x$ as Ideal C, reaching $x=100$, totally forgetting the knowledge that the pipe generates black and white stones in a 50%-50% chance.

**My questions are**:

Which idea is more reasonable?

Is the result of Idea B the same as Idea A?

For Idea D I have no formula yet, how shall I combine 50%-50% prior probability together with the testing result of all 5 stones in Bowl B are White?

Answer (score 1):

Each stone is independent of every other stone. So the answer is $\frac12$.

If you need a more mathematical approach....

Expected no. of white stones = 52.5

Expected no. of black stones = 52.5

Stones taken out = 5

Expected white stones taken out = 2.5 (since black and white are equal, and stones are taken out randomly)

Expected black stones taken out = 2.5

Expected leftover white stones = 52.5 - 2.5 = 50

Comment: But why not $105 * \frac{1}{2} - 5 = 47.5$?

Comment: @athos A simple way to understand:

Comment: If you have $47.5$ expected black and $47.5$ expected white, you have a total of $95$. However, total should be $100$, whether expected or actual.

Answer (score 0):

Idea A is correct. Stones in A are independent from stones in B. Expected number of white stones in A is 50

Idea B should give you the same answer, but you overcomplicate things. $W_A$ and $W_B$ are independent. What do you think $P(W_B=5|W_A=x)$ is?

Comment: This is right, given the (natural) assumption that the pipe emits stones with colors independently of the colors of other stones.  But the OP doesn't actually state that.  I'm sure that the problem was "intended" to assume independence, but I wonder how the answer would change if, let's say, the pipe was governed by a finite state machine that changed stone color after each new stone with probability $r \not= 1/2$.